# Angular Material layout="column" makes divs stack on top of each other on IE

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Hey Angular Material developers. 
Angular Material sure is a beautiful framework, but IE does not like it one bit.

I am trying to use the layout=column when on mobile view(width < 600px). Here is the [responsive layout documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/layout/options).

Both Chrome and Firefox works well, but when opened on IE(ver. 11), something unpleasant happens.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGQmYX

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="StarterApp">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:300,400,500,700,400italic">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
    <style>
        .md-toolbar-tools h1 {
            font-size: inherit;
            font-weight: inherit;
            margin: inherit;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body layout="column" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <md-toolbar layout="row">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <md-button ng-click="toggleSidenav('left')" hide-gt-sm class="md-icon-button">
                <md-icon aria-label="Menu" md-svg-icon="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/68133/menu.svg"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <div layout="row" flex>
        <md-sidenav layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')">

        </md-sidenav>
        <div layout="column" flex id="content">
            <md-content layout="column" flex class="md-padding">
                <div layout="column">
                    <div flex>
                        I'm above on mobile, and to the left on larger devices.
                    </div>
                    <div flex>
                        I'm below on mobile, and to the right on larger devices.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </md-content>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial']);
        app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdSidenav', function ($scope, $mdSidenav) {
            $scope.toggleSidenav = function (menuId) {
                $mdSidenav(menuId).toggle();
            };
        }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I have simplified the code so layout is column all the time.

Is there a fix to this? I am hitting my head on my table so hard I am about to faint.

Comment: Do you want something like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXbJVN?editors=101  ?

Comment: Yeah I simplified the code to make my problem stand out, the problem persist when you adjust your window width<600px on IE in your case.

Comment: I am not sure(cz I use linux and don't have IE) but I think the heights of these divs are causing the problem. Try to add a min-height in the styles of these divs and see if this works..

Comment: It works! But not very ideally...CodePan updated. I guess this is the way I have to go at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this helps but I once had this problem on chrome and adding `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` in the beginning of the document solves the problem